# Changing css as per screen resolution

Tags: css, asp.net, screen-resolution

My webpage is showing different sized text in different computer resolutions. I need to fix it using CSS.

I have idea about screen-size and how to do it using CSS. I applied that in my webpage but its not affecting the other desktops and laptops, having different screen resolution.

Can anybody help me out to fix this issue and if there is any way out to change CSS based on screen resolution.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried? [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You should use media-queries like:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
     body {font-size: 12px;}
}
```

you can use min-width, max-width and also mix these

for full details check out this page: 
[Media Queries CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

***Most common Queries are:***

Small devices (tablets, 768px and up): @media (min-width: **768px**)

Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up): @media (min-width: **992px**)

Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up): @media (min-width: **1200px**)

Comment: My screen resolution is 1600 X 900. So, it means that my screen width is 1600? right?

Comment: The querie uses the size of the browser window. so if you are using your browser in full screen the width should be 1600.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `media Queries` like this-

```
@media (min-width: 700px), handheld and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Go with the link for more details -

**[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)**

and also don't forget `meta tag` in `head`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: My screen resolution is 1600 X 900. So, it means that my screen width is 1600? right?